# Buddypress 'Like' Button error

Tags: jquery, wordpress, buddypress

Unfortunately I cant give a link or preview of the issue I have as the site under strict Non-Disclosure Agreement.  But, below is whats happening, maybe someone has had the same problem and knows how to fix it.

I have a buddypress install on Wordpress, both the latest versions and all plugins up to date.  When ever I click on a 'Like' button from any of the posts I have put on there via different users, it doesn't function correctly, for some reason, it re-loads the header inside either a 'div' or 'li' depending what page the user is currently on and doesn't register the 'Like'.

Also getting the following jQuery error on click:

"Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/."

Once again, apologies for being a bit vague on this, I would love to be able to provide a demo link but its not possible.

Any help would be amazing!

Andy

Comment: BuddyPress doesn't have a Like button. Are you using a plugin or localising the "favorite" text?

Comment: Hi @henrywright sorry for taking a while to reply, been away on holiday.  Apologies, I meant the 'Favourite' button. I have disabled the 'Wall' plugin and 'Cover Photo' plugin to make sure that they werent causing the issue.  Unfortunately it still remains.  Really wish I could show an example, but hard with not being able to show the site to anyone.

Comment: Whats even stranger, is that it doesnt do it when the user is an admin!?